# Error: No resource identifier found for attribute `requestLegacyExternalStorage` and `preserveLegacyExternalStorage` in package `android`

Tags: java, android, debugging, adb, apktool

I have decompiled APK using `apktool d demoapp.apk` then compiling `apk` using `apktool b demoapp.apk` but at compile time it throws the error

`brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1):`

Here `No resource identifier found` for attribute `preserveLegacyExternalStorage` in package `android`

The same error appears for `requestLegacyExternalStorage` as well

Comment: did you check this issue? https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1880

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Yes I have checked this : github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1880

Comment: I am using apk tool version 2.4.1

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to modify its source before recompile it (resource will not be modified), use -r flag when decompile the apk. I have the same problem, and always get unknown resource problem when recompile it. It solve when I use -r flag when decompile the apk.

```
# apktool -r d demo.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

You should compile against SDK 29 and maybe use the most recent build tools for aapt to know this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing helps, the following undocumented command may help (see https://github.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/issues/1842#issuecomment-522616705):

```
apktool empty-framework-dir
```

Run it then try to re-build apk again

```
apktool b example.apk.dir example.apk
```

Other things to try:

1. Upgrade `apktool`: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/
2. Ignore resources with `-r` flag if you don't need them (e.g. you only need to modify the source code):

```
apktool -r d example.apk
```